# wpf datagrid очистить

Tags: wpf, datagrid

заполняю DataGrid

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

sqlitecommand = new SQLiteCommand("select * from " + name, sqliteconnection);
SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlitecommand);
adapter.Fill(ds);
dgrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

теперь мне нужно очистить DataGrid

`dgrid.Items.Clear();`

получаю

`System.InvalidOperationException: "Операция недопустима, когда ItemsSource используется. Вместо этого получите доступ и измените элементы с помощью ItemsControl.ItemsSource."`

как очистить `DataGrid`?

Comment: Когда вы пишете `dgrid.Items.Add(...)` (или как там у него правильно), то в таком варианте коллекцией данных будет являться сам контрол, тогда вы можете уже сделать `dgrid.Items.Clear()`, что приведет к очистке его данных. Когда вы делаете `dgrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;`, то контрол лишь отображает данные из заданной коллекции, не более. То есть в таком случае у вас источником данных является `ds.Tables[0].DefaultView`, которую вам и надо очищать. Ну или делайте костыли, обнуляйте `ItemsSource`. Вообще, советую использовать привязки, ибо текущий ваш подход ужасен...

Comment: Вы назначаете ItemsSource, для очистки тоже работайте с ним, т.е. dataGrid.ItemsSource = null; Так же из [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items?view=netframework-4.8#-----------): Если задано свойство ItemsSource, Items коллекция становится доступна только для чтения и имеет фиксированный размер. Если ItemsSource используется, установка свойства ItemsSource в значение null удаляет коллекцию и восстанавливает использование Items